# For Cassandra kundera.client.lookup.class options

Tags: cassandra, kundera

In order to configure kundera for Cassandra, I notice there are 3 possible options for **kundera.client.lookup.class** as below

1. com.impetus.client.cassandra.pelops.PelopsClientFactory
2. com.impetus.kundera.client.cassandra.dsdriver.DSClientFactory
3. com.impetus.client.cassandra.thrift.ThriftClientFactory

I am not sure of the Pros and Cons of the above 3 and hence not sure which one to use. Please help me decide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, I found the following

**Don't use PelopsClient** as its not in active development as mentioned by @karthik , but more importantly because of the issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523006/com-impetus-kundera-kunderaexception-org-apache-thrift-transport-ttransportexce)

**Data Stax Driver is better than thrift** client as it over comes few limitations of thrift and they use a different binary protocol specific to cassandra which gives a better performance. Refer [Datastax java driver support for Cassandra using Kundera](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Datastax-java-driver-support-for-Cassandra-using-Kundera)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `com.impetus.client.cassandra.thrift.ThriftClientFactory`. It is the implementation using just Cassandra's thrift api.

`PelopsClient` is not in active development.

`DSClient` is built over datastax driver of cassandra.

There is no real advantage of using either `DSClient` or `ThriftClient`.